# Invalid loop variable type expected Lead was Opportunity

Tags: apex, opportunity, leads

I am iterating over two for-loops that each get a list of new sObjects, in this case it is Leads and Opportunities respectively. However I keep getting an error when I try compile the code. Please see code snippet below:

```
Set<Id> ownerIds = new Set<Id>(); 
Set<String> oppStages = new Set<String>();

 for (Lead leadObj : trigger.new) {
        ownerIds.add(leadObj.OwnerId);
 }

 for(Opportunity oppObj : trigger.new) {   
        oppStages.add(oppObj.StageName);  
 }
```

However I get an `Invalid loop variable type expected Lead was Opportunity` error. Why am I getting this error? What am I doing wrong?

Here is some more context on the use case:
I need to write a trigger that will check if a user has more than 2 open opportunities and if that condition is met then the user should be prevented from creating an opportunity for themselves. Any ideas on how I can do this? Will this be a Master-Detail relationship? How do I go about doing this because a trigger is only fired on a single object and not two. In my case I need to listen for events on both Lead and Opportunity objects. Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in which trigger you're executing? If opportunity, second block is valid, if lead first block is valid.

Comment: On Lead object. So basically you can't run a trigger on two different objects at the same time?

Comment: trigger runs in object context. if you update opportunity, it'll call opportunity trigger. If you update lead, it'll call lead trigger. And the variables trigger.new/old/newmap/oldmaps it'll hold that object reference. 

If you still need to access other object, you can query those objects and iterate on those. E.g. on lead there will be opp Id and you can use those.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It has definitely gone a long way. I'm not too sure if you can assist but what I want to do is write a trigger that will check if a user has more than 2 open opportunities and if that condition is met then they should not be allowed to create a lead for themselves.